# Why doesn't System.Threading.Timer callback fire?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, timer

I'm **not** using a Windows Form Timer--I'm using a System.Threading.Timer. No exceptions are raised when instantiating the timer, and to my understanding, System.Threading.Timer's do not need to be explicitly started.

I've tried using a System.Timers.Timer (See comments in code) and changing the signature of the callback with no luck. Inside the callback method, I stubbed in some EventLog writes, and not even the first writes to the event log. All I see in the Event Log is MyService.OnStart fired followed by MyService started (these are both from the OnStart event). Why aren't the timer callback events firing?

```
public partial class MyService : ServiceBase
{

    private static System.Threading.Timer timer;

    public MyService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("MyService"))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                "MyService", "MyServiceLog");
        }
        eventLog1.Source = "MyService";
        eventLog1.Log = "MyServiceLog";
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("MyService.OnStart event fired");

        // setup timer to poll and execute an event
        //Timer timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(CheckCalls), null, 0, 10000);
        try
        {
            timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new System.Threading.TimerCallback(CheckCalls), null, 0, 10000);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry(ex.Message + " Stacktrace: " + ex.StackTrace);
        }

        eventLog1.WriteEntry("MyServicestarted");

        GC.KeepAlive(timer);
    }
}
```

and the callback method, CheckCalls:

```
private static void CheckCalls(object objectState)
    {
        EventLog eventLog1 = new EventLog("MyServiceLog", "DAVIDWIN7", "MyService");
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("MyService is polling");
    }
```

---

Arg--For some reason when you Build->Clean Solution, then Build->Build Solution, Visual Studio does not rebuild your setup project. I believe my code above works fine, but I had tried many different fixes without explicitly right-clicking the setup project and selecting Build.

I thought Clean Solution would force all projects to be rebuilt on next build???

Comment: `GC.KeepAlive(timer);` definitely isn't needed; your service holds a reference to the timer.  You sure your service starts?  You sure it doesn't immediately stop afterwards?

Comment: Have you tried attaching the debugger to your service when running and sticking a breakpoint in the `CheckCalls` method?

Comment: @Will: I'm pretty certain the service starts. My Event Log registers two stubbed events (both inside OnStart) and doesn't register the OnStop event until I uninstall the service

Comment: @Andras: I can't attach to the MyService.vshost.exe, but I can attach to the MyService.exe (after right-clicking setup project, installing, and starting service), though no symbols load. I also have everything in CheckCalls wrapped in a try-catch, where the catch writes to the event log

Comment: Somewhere amidst my code changes and reinstalls it fixed itself :/ I also removed the `GC.KeepAlive(timer)` line. However, the Event Log entries weren't being written inside CheckCalls. I've tried changing constructors to `EventLog(string logName)` and that doesn't seem to work either. Any ideas?

Comment: @David if you attach to your service (yep, not the .vshost. version) and no symbols are loaded, *you're doing something else wrong*.  Most likely what you **think** is your newly built service is, in fact, some older version that does NOT have a timer.

Comment: @Jeff: I posted an answer that was deleted. The problem was resolved when I manually built the setup project. The next time I installed the service after reverting to the code in my post, it worked. I have since changed back to a System.Timers.Timer (with callback signature changed) and it still works.

Comment: @Will: The problem must have been with the Event Log writes. When I modified it to write to a text file, it seems to do the trick.

Comment: @david glad you figured it out; see, I told you the problem laid elsewhere!  If you want to close this question out, provide an answer with details about your fix (a simple paragraph is fine; cull it from your comments here) and you can select it after a couple days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's got to be an error with the timer thread writing to the event log.

I got it working on my computer but I replaced all the eventlog with Console.writeline because I didn't want to mess with my event log permissions.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but this was the fix. Something was wrong with the event log writes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the account under which the service is running has access to the eventlog?

Comment: I did, but thank you. I tried a LocalSystem, LocalService, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please can you go and download this test application which mirrors exactly the scenario you are talking about:

https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0Bw_NnV9fhgmgMThjNDgzOTgtODNiOC00NDE1LWEyMTYtNzVhOTMyNzlmZjZk&hl=en&authkey=CMuupNkC

I've just created this.  It's a service that effectively uses the same code as you.  The only difference is that I have used the toolbox to drag and drop an eventlog on to the service designer - setting the log to 'Application' and the source to 'Service1'.

Open a VS command prompt at the project folder, go to `bin\debug` and run `installutil windowsservice1.exe` - specifying some credentials (so you're installing the dev service directly from your bin output folder).

Start the service and monitor the application log - it will write every ten seconds as you expect to see from your code.

Assuming this works on your machine(tm) like it does on my machine(tm) then I would suggest that the problem is the event logging itself, or, horror of horrors - your service isn't running from your build output folder (most of the devs in my team insist on running their dev services from a different folder and then swear when they forget to actually update the binaries when they start debugging it!).

As I suggested in my comment, you really need to be able to attach the debugger to this and breakpoint the callback to verify that it's not getting fired.  I never rely on the eventlog for diagnostics messages simply because the log might be full, or permissions might prevent you etc etc - it might be a windows platform component, but it's not as reliable as I would like.

The debugger, however, rarely lies (unless the deployed binaries are out of date ;) ).  Compile a debug build of your project and *make sure it's the one that is installed in the services list*, start it up and then attach *directly to the service exe* (there's no point trying to attach to [service].vshost.exe - VS cannot auto-attach or host windows services as the only way they can run is via svchost.exe shelling them).

Hope this helps.